# Drawing ellipse in R

Tags: r

I want to make ellipse in R. The code is given below:

```
library(car)
A      <- matrix(c(2.2, 0.4, 0.4, 2.8), nrow=2)
ellipse(c(0, 0), shape=A, radius=0.98, col="red", lty=2)
```

But this code produces the following error:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: supply the argument `add=FALSE` and it will create a new plot instead of trying to add to an existing one.  There is also an `ellipse` package that I've used if you want another option.

Comment: Thanks @Justin for your help. Would you mind to change your comment into answer!!! So that I can accept your answer for future users. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

supply the argument `add=FALSE` and it will create a new plot instead of trying to add to an existing one. There is also an `ellipse` package that I've used if you want another option.