# R: How to sample from the geometric space outside a 4D hyper ellipse?

Tags: r, ellipse

**Original title** (in-precise): How to find all vectors that satisfy a 4-unknown non-linear inequalities?

---

The question is to find a space C, so that any 4x1 vector x in C satisfies:

```
t(x) %*% t(Q) %*% Q %*% x > a,
```

in which `Q` is a `100 x 4` matrix I already know, and `a` is a positive constant.

I tried to find the solution from packages such as `ellipse`, `rootSolve`, and `bvpSolve`. But I can't reach a suitable solution.

Any idea or solution will be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remark:** the algorithm below can be used to sample from the surface / manifold of a 4D hyper ellipse, or its inner space, too.

I have changed your question title. It is impossible to list all solutions, although such space has simple mathematical representation. We can at our best sample from such space.

---

**Transformation from Ellipse to Sphere**

Here is some mathematics based on Cholesky factorization. Alternatively, consider symmetric Eigen decomposition, and I have a demonstration / comparison between these two at [Obtain vertices of the ellipse on an ellipse covariance plot (created by `car::ellipse`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40316331/4891738), with nice figures for the geometry.

[image]

Since `Q` is known, `R` is known. The following R code gets `R`:

```
R <- chol(crossprod(Q))
```

**`y` is from the hypersphere with radius greater than `sqrt(a)`.** If we can sample `y` from such space, we can then map it to `x` by solving a triangular system:

```
x <- backsolve(R, y)
```

---

**Sampling of `y`**

We can use [n-sphere coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates) to parametrize such space. For 4D space, we have:

[image]

The following R function samples `n` y-vectors from such space. Because of finite representation of floating point numbers, we can't have infinity radius but `.Machine$double.xmax` at the best. But we also use an optional argument `rmax`, if we want a more restricted radius.

```
ry <- function (n, rmin, rmax = NA) {
  if (is.na(rmax)) rmax <- .Machine$double.xmax
  if (rmin > rmax) stop("larger `rmax` expected!")
  r <- runif(n, rmin, rmax)
  phi1 <- runif(n, 0, pi)
  phi2 <- runif(n, 0, 2 * pi)
  phi3 <- runif(n, 0, 2 * pi)
  matrix(c(r * cos(phi1), 
           r * sin(phi1) * cos(phi2),
           r * sin(phi1) * sin(phi2) * cos(phi3),
           r * sin(phi1) * sin(phi2) * sin(phi3)),
         nrow = 4L, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(paste0("y", 1:4), NULL))
  }
```

Try some examples:

```
## radius between 4 and 10
set.seed(0); ry(5, 4, 10)
#         [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
#y1  7.5594886 -5.31049687 -6.1388372 -3.5991830 -3.728597
#y2  5.1402945  0.47936481  0.4799181 -2.5085948 -6.480402
#y3  0.2614002 -1.68833263 -0.1950092 -5.9975328 -4.213166
#y4 -2.0859078  0.02440839 -0.9452077  0.3052708  3.954674

## radius between 4 and "inf"
set.seed(0); ry(5, 4)
#             [,1]           [,2]           [,3]           [,4]           [,5]
#y1  1.299100e+308 -4.531902e+307 -6.588856e+307 -4.983772e+307 -6.442420e+307
#y2  8.833607e+307  4.090831e+306  5.150993e+306 -3.473640e+307 -1.119710e+308
#y3  4.492167e+306 -1.440799e+307 -2.093047e+306 -8.304756e+307 -7.279678e+307
#y4 -3.584637e+307  2.082977e+305 -1.014498e+307  4.227070e+306  6.833046e+307
```

I have chosen to use each column than each row as a sample, to make matrix computation easier later.

---

**Transforming `y` to `x`**

Now assume we have

```
set.seed(0); Q <- matrix(runif(10 * 4), 10L, 4L)
```

We get `R`

```
R <- chol(crossprod(Q))
#         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
#[1,] 2.176848 1.420882 1.2517326 1.4481875
#[2,] 0.000000 1.077816 0.1045581 0.4646328
#[3,] 0.000000 0.000000 1.2284251 0.3961126
#[4,] 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.9019771
```

Suppose you have `a = 4`, then we map `y` to `x`:

```
a <- 4
set.seed(0); y <- ry(5, sqrt(a), 10)  ## we set an `rmax` here
x <- backsolve(R, y)  ## each column is a sample of `x`
#           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
#[1,]  0.7403534 -1.49866534 -2.2359350  2.0269516  2.948561
#[2,]  5.5481682  0.41827601  0.7024109 -1.7606720 -7.288339
#[3,]  0.9373905 -1.01984708  0.1430660 -4.4180688 -4.749419
#[4,] -2.2616584  0.01995357 -0.8367956  0.2995693  4.299268
```

---

**Checking**

We can check that the above `x` does satisfy our requirement.

```
z <- Q %*% x
ax <- colSums(x ^ 2)  ## value of `diag(x'Q'Qx)`
#[1] 84.15453 17.00795 24.77044 43.33361 85.85250
```

They are all greater than 4.