# R Leaflet: draw curved line between points

Tags: r, r-leaflet

I'm trying to draw curved lines between nearby locations in leaflet.

All the responses to similar questions on SO suggest using `gcIntermediate()` from the `geosphere` package, however that does not work for nearby locations as the curvature is so slight that it will still look like a straight line.

So starting with two pairs of lat/lon coordinates (origin x/y, end x/y), is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: this is a tough question, trying to figure it out.

Comment: see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820683/how-to-plot-ellipse-given-a-general-equation-in-r