# How do I draw a circle of the form aX^2 + bY^2 + cXY + dX + eY = f in R

Tags: r, plot

Title explains the question. I know how to draw standard circles and elipses but have no idea how to plot an equation like that

Comment: You could find a bunch of coordinate pairs on various ways, but it's a lot easier to work in polar form, e.g. `ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 2*pi), y = 1), aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + coord_polar()`

Comment: Run `sos::findFn('ellipse plot')`, the first hit gets you to CRAN package [`PlaneGeometry`.](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=PlaneGeometry).

Comment: Maybe this post helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41820683/12158757